# wysiwyg editor liferay in portlet from xhtml

Tags: primefaces, xhtml, liferay, wysiwyg, portlet

how can I add wysiwyg editor in a portlet from an xhtml page?

I tried:

```
<liferay-ui: input-editor value = "#{BackBean.foro.desarrollo}">
```

but generates error:

```
/html/js/editor/editor.wysiwyg.default.jsp JSP File not found
```

I use liferay 6.0.6 
with liferay faces 3.0.3 and Primefaces 3.5

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

liferay-ui tags are liferay's custom jsp tags, you can not use them in xhtml page.

Better you use primefaces tag for wysiwyg editor.

e.g.

```
<p:editor value="#{BackBean.foro.desarrollo}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Liferay Faces Portal has a Facelet equivalent of the liferay-ui:input-editor JSP tag. I would recommend that you upgrade to version 3.0.4-ga5 (the latest at the time of this writing) and see if it works.

Comment: Hi Neil: I have been able to put liferay-ui:input-editor in my JSF porlet. But when the component shows in page, appears this message:

var oldEditor = CKEDITOR.instances['A7976:CrearForo:j_idt14']; if (oldEditor) >{oldEditor.destroy(true);delete window['A7976:CrearForo:j_idt14'];} if (oldEditor){var customDataProcessorLoaded = true;}else{var customDataProcessorLoaded = false;}

Also, sometimes, not load the component if I refresh the page

Could you help me please?

I use liferay portal 6.0.6 with liferay faces 3.0.4 GA5 according your reply

Comment: [parallel thread at Liferay Forums](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/42973805)